# Insert row in UiTableView does not update rest cell’s indexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

Say i’m loading UITableview with each UITextView inside each cell as subview.And i’ve assigned indexPath.row as tags for each textview.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"userDetails";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 60)];
    NSString * myString = [contentArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    textView.text= myString;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    textView.tag = indexPath.row;//assign tags to textview
    [textView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [cell addSubview:textView];

    return cell;
}
```

Below method gets called once the user taps on any textview.I’m seeing proper tag values printed when i tap on any textviews.

```
-(void) action:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"TESTING TAP");
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    NSLog (@"%d",[tapRecognizer.view tag]);
}
```

Now i would like to insert row in my tableview,say at index 3.

What i did is simple,

```
[contentArray1 insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"added cell”] atIndex:3];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Now when i try to tap on any textviews after the inserted cell,i’m able to see the old tag values.Meaning,after row gets inserted to tableview at index=3,when i tap on textview i can see tag=2,then again when i tap on next cell’s textview i can see tag=2,it should be 3.

My question is,once we insert any row/cell in tableview,the tableview will not refresh other cell tags/index?….

I can fix it by calling **reloadVisibleCells** method.But i’m looking out for better solution.I don’t want to refresh whole screen just for inserting a row.Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: even though you delete a row or insert a row, you need to call table reload data. It is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that inserting/deleting rows doesn't cause reloading of other rows, and this is the expected and correct behavior. However, since `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called for those other rows, they are still configured with old (now obsolete) tags.

You can fix it in a number of ways (off the top of my head):

- subclass `UITableViewCell` and store the represented object itself as its property (instead of the object's index)
- associate the object with the `UITableViewCell` with `objc_setAssociatedObject()`
- use `-[UITableView indexPathForCell:]` instead of tags to figure out a cell's real index path.